# Tagging like github or gitlab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tagging, acts-as-taggable-on

I want to introduce github like tagging in my app, where a repo has some predefined tags/labels and only those tags can be used on issues/PRs. Project can `have_many issues`. Tags are related to both repos and issues, as in issues `has_many tags` and repos `has_many tags`. I can't seem to figure out how to implement it. I am using [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on). So, I initialize the tag_list of repo when it is first created with:

```
repo.tag_list = 'bug, feature, improvement, inspiration, discussion, help'
```

I am allowing user to add tags at the same time issue is created (ie on new form of issues). Now how do I validate in issue model that tags being added is in the tag_list of the repo on which issue is being created?

Comment: Question is unclear. How do you validate what?

Comment: validate if tags user has added on issues are valid tags ie tags exist in the `repo.tag_list`

Comment: You need "validates inclusion in". See here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates

Comment: Or this shortcut: http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_inclusion_of

Comment: I have to validate if tag used on issue exists in the tag_list of repo. I can't hard code it and just validate a fixed array in issue. tag_list of repo can be updated and more tags can be added to it.

Comment: Yeah, so? Use the dynamic tag_list. What's the problem with this? I mean, other than incurring a damn database query upon each validation.

Comment: How do I even access repo model inside issues model? self.repo.tag_list won't work inside issues model.

Comment: Custom validators will help: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators

Comment: Things like issue.repo doesn't work until after issue is saved. And thats the thing i need to validate using issue.repo.tag_list (or some other way) before issue is saved.

Comment: There must be something wrong in the code. I'm pretty sure it should work. If you assign a repo to the issue before saving, I don't see how it wouldn't work.

Comment: Issue model needs to know about tag_list of repo and I can't think of way of do so before issue is saved.

Comment: okay. let me recheck. I am pretty sure I have added issues.repo = @repo before saving it

Comment: okay. I feel stupid. I have used things `repo` all over the model of issue. I think I got nilclass error over typo. Sorry,  Sergio. Thanks for putting up with me.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)